# Setting properties on anonymously created Objects in Objective C

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, properties, anonymous-types

if I have a method/function in OBJ-C that returns an object. I often Use:

```
    return [[MyEventArgs alloc] init];
```

//Also want to set MyEventArgs property Height to be 100.

If I wanted to set some properties on that object in the creation of it. How do I do that?
In C# I can do:

```
return new MyEventArgs{Height = 100};
```

What is the syntax for doing this in OBJ-C?

Another question regarding the same topic is if I can create objects and properties dynamically in OBJ-C like in C#?

for instance, I can do this in C# (a feature that is great when working with link/lambda)

```
 List<object> aList = new List<object>();
 aList.Add(new { Height = 100 });
```

How do I accomplish this in OBJ-C?

//Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such shorthand in Objective-C. You'd have to name the variable in some way to call the appropriate methods on it.

Comment: None of the two examples above can be accomplished in Obj-C? Thats kind of weird. I'm finding myself wanting to do this a lot. And the extra syntax really irretates me. Thanks for the answer however!

Comment: You could create some C macros that will help. Or there is an initialization shorthand like the first example for C structs, just not for full objects.

Comment: This is not strictly true, what the OP needs is a custom init method, the only thing you CAN'T do is decide which properties to set or not, but you can create custom init methods (or convenience methods like Eugenes answer)

Comment: Simon: They're two different issues. The idea was he wanted a shorthand without creating a new initializer for each set. Similar to C struct initialization CGPoint p = {.x = 1.0f, .y = 2.0f}

Comment: Coming from a .NET background I know exactly what he wants to do, but the answer of saying to create and object then call some accessor methods is not particularly solving his problem, if he ALWAYS wants to set the height of the object at instatiation then why not put it in a custom init method, you didn't offer him that explanation.

Comment: Yes. I understand the concept of creating an "initWithHeight"-method for this example. But this was just an example. Lets say I have an many classes with many properties and need to create objects from them and placing in i.e an array, I just want to be able to set the objects properties directly. And regarding my second example, which I think is even worse that objective c does not permit, itäs really convenient to be able to create anonoumus objects with dynamically instantiated properties on the fly. e.i when lifting properties from an database and creating custom objects out of them.

Comment: @ObjectiveCoder: You CAN do your second example, just not without adding some stuff to do the heavy lifting (or just use an NSDictionary)

Answer (score 1):

There are no such shorthands, but you, for instance, could create a custom constructor like

```
+ (id)myObjectWithHeight:(CGFloat)height;
```

The constructor code would be:

```
+ (id)myObjectWithHeight:(CGFloat)height {
  MyObject *object = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
  object.height = height;
  return object;
}
```

And use it like

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[MyObject myObjectWithHeight:100]];
```

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse I could do this. Or just define a custom init-constructor. But that's not what I wanted.